# Selenium Testing - Test if Clicking Button Opens Correct Items

Tags: python, django, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I have two buttons on my page, one for viewing a pdf (opens in new tab) and one for downloading pdf (downloads it directly by adding the attachment header.

Here's my testing code so far:

```
def test_study_popover_view_clicked(self):
    cls.selenium_chrome.get('https://www.shenkan-associates.com/')

    try:
        target_element_chrome = cls.selenium_chrome.find_element_by_id('study-item-7')
        target_element_chrome.click()
        popover_element_chrome = cls.selenium_chrome.find_element_by_class_name('popover')
        popover_view_button_element_chrome = cls.selenium_chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector('.popover > .popover-content > .popover-actions > .study-view'))
    except NoSuchElementException as ex:
        self.fail(ex.msg)

    nt.assert_true(popover_element_chrome.is_displayed())
    nt.assert_true(popover_view_button_element_chrome.is_displayed())
    nt.assert_equal(popover_view_button_element_chrome.text, 'View')

    popover_view_button_element_chrome.click()

def test_study_popover_download_clicked(self):
    cls.selenium_chrome.get('https://www.shenkan-associates.com/')

    try:
        target_element_chrome = cls.selenium_chrome.find_element_by_id('study-item-7')
        target_element_chrome.click()
        popover_element_chrome = cls.selenium_chrome.find_element_by_class_name('popover')
        popover_download_button_element_chrome = cls.selenium_chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector('.popover > .popover-content > .popover-actions > .study-download'))
    except NoSuchElementException as ex:
        self.fail(ex.msg)

    nt.assert_true(popover_element_chrome.is_displayed())
    nt.assert_true(popover_download_button_element_chrome.is_displayed())
    nt.assert_equal(popover_download_button_element_chrome.text, 'Download')

    popover_download_button_element_chrome.click()
```

As you can see I click the download and view button elements. at the end of each method.  Clicking view should open a pdf in a separate tab.  Clicking download should start to download the pdf directly.

I just need a way to test that the buttons are doing what they should.

How can I test this?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Stuck on how to check whether the pdf opens in a new tab/downloads when view and download buttons are clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing the download button, you can check file count in download folder before and after clicking the download button.

Comment: Well that would only work on my personal machine.  I want this to run in containers/in a CI framework like Bitbucket Pipelines or CircielCI.  All I care about is whether it is loading the correct item from the database into a new tab and whether it's opening the correct item from the database for download.